# Changing components of included layout in the run time

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background, include

I have common_views.xml where I define views which is common to all the other layouts and include this common_views.xml to these other layouts.

common_views.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/water_room_common"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/bag" android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/storage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />
    <RelativeLayout...> ... </RelativeLayout>
   ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is one of such layouts where I include common_views.xml, I called it water_room_wall1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wall1Layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wall1withkey"
    tools:context=".FireRoomActivity" >

<include layout="@layout/common_views" android:id="@+id/common_views" />

....
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity I want to programmatically change background of imagebutton @id/bag in common_views.xml:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.water_room_wall1);
            parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.wall1Layout);
    }

    ...
ImageButton newItem  =(ImageButton)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.common_views).findViewById(R.id.bag);
newItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key_stored);
```

}

But this drops all the other components(they disappear) of water_room_wall1.xml layout and just shows common_views.xml layout with changed imagebutton. Why is that? Is there any method which changes only a component of included layout without affecting parent layout?

Comment: You have the `width` and `height` of your `include`d `layout` as `fill_parent`. Try changing it to `wrap_content`. Changing the `background` of an included `layout` shouldn't "drop" your other `View`s

Comment: did so, nothing changed

Comment: Does everything show as it should if you don't change the `background` of your `ImageButton`? What if you set the `background` to `key_stored` before running, does it show correctly?

Comment: yes, it does.If you mean adding background in xml. I should mention that components of parent layout disappers even when I change something else in the included layout, not only the imagebutton.

Comment: But if you don't change anything in your Java code, nothing disappears? That's strange...I've used this a lot and never had a problem. I also set the `height` `width` in my `<include>` tag also but I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @codeMagic thanks mate for spending your time on this question. 
no I don't change anything before it. Alright, seems like I wasn't running latest version of the code for some reason. Now, it doesn't drop parent layout's components. It's alright. It still drops background image of parent layout however."android:background="@drawable/wall1withkey", as if it isn't there when I change the imagebutton's background at run time

Comment: @codeMagic figured. i actually did change smth before setting imagebuttons background. really sorry for your time. at least now i know that changing included layout doesn't affect parent's components. I wasn't sure before

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working